# Copy public_html from hosting to localhost

Tags: php, xampp, localhost, hosting, cpanel

I want to run website from my localhost (xampp). So, I copied public_html to my htdocs folder and import it database to localhost/phpmyadmin.
I was configuring the file that contain function to connect to database (like username & password).

But, when I run it in browser, nothing is shown besides the following picture :

[image]

Is there a special configuration ?

**EDIT :**
My point is can I run a website just by copying the public_html folder to htdocs?

Answer (score 0):

why dont u just use redirect url from database ?? when u put codes into databese of coz it wont work becaesu of unwanted characters.. and it will display half or like text or something.. if you want to add code into database, use code html tags or add as file, like inc or something.. later u can make read ur file into codes..

Comment: Sorry, that's not what I mean.

I mean, can I run a website just by copying the public_html folder to htdocs?

Comment: yeah.. you can do it. but dont forget config settings something like that  conf['site_url'] on ur config file.. i mean put ur path url to into config..